# Can we extract multiple books data from google books api using googlebooks ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, google-books

I am trying to parse the books data from google api JSON response

below link gives me books data for multiple books

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=you%20can%20win&maxresults=40

Using GoogleBooks ruby gem, i could hardly figure out the way to get data of the first books

Ex:first.book.tittle, first.book.author

Can someone please help me out getting the data of all books in the JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like that:

```
books = GoogleBooks::API.search('Douglas Rockford')
books.each do |book|
  puts book.author
end
```